# Setting QTableView width depends on model columns

Tags: qt, layout

I have a custom QAbstractTableModel for my data and the model currently contains fixed number of columns (12). I also have a custom QTableView to display this model. When I added this widget to my dialog, it always clapped the last few columns like this [image]

I use standard layouts (QFormLayout, QVBoxLayout) for adding widgets to the dialog and I haven't specify minimumSize() for my widgets, hoping the layout engine to calculate the best for me.

So, how do I setup the model class / QTableview class so that it will automatically expand to show all the columns? Or how do I make the minimumSize of my tableView depends on the width of table columns?

(I don't want to hardcode the pixel values for the windows, as whenever the columns changes, I will have to adjust the values again manually)

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, scroll bars are inside your table, not outside of it. `QTableView` extends `QAbstractScrollArea`, which creates them, when content does not fit into viewport. Minimal size of viewport is controlled by method `QSize QAbstractScrollArea::maximumViewportSize () const` (which is not virtual, by the way).

I think, the best way would be to save `QWidget::saveGeometry()` (is it `QMainMindow`?) and `QTableView::horizontalHeader()->saveState()` in `QSettings` in your widget's destructor, and resotre them in constructor.

Comment: It is a QDialog, but I have another similiar case on QMainWindow

Comment: In both ways use saveGeometry/restoreGeometry.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. AFAIK, using QSetting on Win-platform will write something to registry, which is not I want my app to do. So, are there any alternative to achieve the same effect? Also, As the dialog is fixed, I don't think saving widget's geometry really do help for calculating the proper width of widget.

Comment: 1. You could use QSettings with IniFormat parameter. 2. Indeed, for a dialog with fixed size it's not an option, that's why I suggest you allow user to change sizes. Alternative to this is to calculate horizontal header width and to set dialog's width manually.